# Embeded YouTube videos not loading

Tags: html, video, youtube, youtube-api

Our current implementation for YouTube videos use standard `<object>` from API documentation and is no longer loading correctly.
It shows an empty Object with link to YouTube page.

Created an example using code from documentation and error is reproduce-able.

Anybody know if there's another way to use the embedded code from YouTube?

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <object width="640" height="390">
        <param name="movie"
            value="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&autoplay=1"></param>
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&autoplay=1"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            allowscriptaccess="always"
            width="640" height="390"></embed>
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

API Documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: Instead of `embed` use the `iframe`

Comment: This example was taken from the API Docu. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=de#AS3_Object_Embeds

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. That would be a possibility, but we didnt wanted to change that part of the code, because many iframes contain specific styling and it would be a litle overhead for us. Do you know if this <object> aproach is still supported by YouTube?

Comment: Its much easier because the `<object>` already is an overhead but the `iframe` styling is nothing much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You don't need all those thing just do it like this..

<object width="420" height="315"
data="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</object>
```

OR

```
<embed width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
```

Comment: That did the trick!! Apparently all the parameters from the API Version cause some kind of problem. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Most [YouTube](http://YouTube.com) videos are been embedded in an `iframe` tag like this:

```
<iframe src="link_to_video"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iframe youtube embedded option.

Or you can do it your self on you tube click on share under you tube video and click on embed.Copy and paste code in your html.

1. Share 2. Embed 3. Copy & Paste

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be solved, if the video is called over the API url.
https://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&video_id=oPEJzOTgQCE&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&rel=0

This can use all the extra parameters and works the exact same way as the other URL.

```
<object data="https://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&amp;video_id=oPEJzOTgQCE&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flash_236856494" width="312" height="173"><param name="scale" value="showAll"><param name="salign" value="tl"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="update" value="true"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="bgcolor" value="#DADADA"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"><param name="flashvars" value="youtubeId=oPEJzOTgQCE&amp;autostart=false&amp;suggestedQuality=large"><param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&amp;video_id=oPEJzOTgQCE&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;rel=0"></object>
```